# Are there any package tours that run from Singapore via Malaysia to Siem Riep/Angkor Wat?

Tags: tours, southeast-asia, singapore, malaysia, cambodia

My wife and I love Singapore and I'd like to introduce her to some more of SE Asia.  The easiest way to do that is to start in Singapore and play the history card to go through places like Malacca and Angkor Wat, but I can't find any tours that run through that route - all either fly directly to Siem Riep or via Bangkok.  Are there tours that meet that description?

Comment: Can I ask why you need a package tour?  Those places are firmly on the "banana pancake" tourist trail and you'll have no problems communicating, getting around, booking flights etc on your own, hiring English-speaking guides locally as needed.

Comment: Because sometimes I just like to relax and let someone else deal with the travel planning.  When we travel it's me doing the organizing and I find it quite stressful sometimes.

Comment: [Banana Pancake Trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Pancake_Trail) - wow, today I learned.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the regional airlines offer fly / stay packages, not exactly a "tour" but the basic logistics are covered.  Then you can book daytrips to see the ruins through the front desk.

There are local package tours, but they tend to be geared towards local clientele, so may or may not be suitable for you comfort style or language.  Plus the bus trip from Malaysia through Thailand to Cambodia is fairly long.